# pow large numbers in Python

Tags: python, pow, largenumber

How can I raise large numbers to a power in python?

```
a = 62608558862573792084872798679396455703616395237802859621162736207631538899993
b = 93910650126758265671774994856253142403789359314618444886584691522424141933664
c = pow(a, b)
```

It is impossible to get an answer that way. Are there any ways to raise large numbers to a power to make it work?

Comment: _It is impossible to get an answer that way_ What do you mean "impossible"?  What happens when you try?

Comment: Could be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Why do you need it?  Usually when you need huge numbers it's for cryptography and you really need `a**b % c` which `pow(a,b,c)` provides and is much faster.

Comment: Even using a recursion algorithm for powers, this is too much. I suggest you look into the answer of @MarkTolenen.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I need to implement `pow(h, pow(a, b), n).to_bytes(32, 'big')`  and get the answer. Am I right that `pow(h, pow(a, b, n), n).to_bytes(32, 'big')` equals `pow(h, pow(a, b), n).to_bytes(32, 'big')` ?

Comment: As a general answer about the limitations of `pow()` and alternative methods, see: [Python math range error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43148927/13843268).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you calculate the result to all digits, it has 10^78 digits. That's more than will fit into any RAM of any computer in the world today.

> It is impossible to get an answer that way.

It will be impossible to get a precise answer for a long time, given that Earth only has ~10^50 atoms.

The number 62608558862573792084872798679396455703616395237802859621162736207631538899993 looks like a pseudo prime number (is has only 5 prime factors) as used in cryptography. Cryptography often works with modulo operations to limit the number of digits. You can use [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) to do modulo math as well:

> pow(base, exp, mod=None)
>
> Return base to the power exp; if mod is present, return base to the power exp, modulo mod (computed more efficiently than pow(base, exp) % mod).